# regex: extract 3 specific numbers from a string | example

Tags: regex

given the following 2 lines of strings, for example :

```
May 22 00:46:38.340  prod-lab03c-rd1 fpc4 XETH(4/2): %PFE-6: Link 0 XFP: Low Rx power warning set
[May 24 11:24:28.299 LOG: Notice] MIC(0/1) link 1 SFP receive power low  warning set
```

i would like to store in 3 variables the following numbers :

```
[1] the 1st number after the "(", it could be 1 or more digits
[2] the 1st number after the "/", it could be 1 or more digits
[3] the first number after the "(L|l)ink" word, it could be 1 or more digits
```

could you please assist me on this please ?

many thanks

Comment: SLAX is the language that i am using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the first number after the first `(`, we can use `.*\((\d+)`. Then to get the first number after the `/`, we can use `/(\d+)\)`. And then to get the first number after "link": `[lL]ink (\d+)`. We put these together to get

```
^.*\((\d+)/(\d+)\).*[lL]ink (\d+)
```

The three numbers will be in the three groups

Answer (score 1):

This works here

```
\((.*?)/(.*?)\).*?[Ll]ink (\d+)
```

Give your input it will give back

```
group 1  group 2 group 3
4        2       0
0        1       1
```

Answer (score 0):

A full tested example in Perl :

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @a;

$a[0] = "May 22 00:46:38.340  prod-lab03c-rd1 fpc4 XETH(4/2): %PFE-6: Link 0 XFP: Low Rx power warning set\n";
$a[1] = "[May 24 11:24:28.299 LOG: Notice] MIC(0/1) link 1 SFP receive power low  warning set";

foreach (@a) {
    print "\$1=$1|\$2=$2|\$3=$3\n" if m!\((\d+)/(\d+)\).*?(?:L|l)ink\s+(\d+)!;
}
```

The output :

```
$1=4|$2=2|$3=0
$1=0|$2=1|$3=1
```